# How to pass data in selected cell to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, label, global-variables, tableview

The piece of code below prints the content of whichever cell is clicked on in my TableView.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    print(self.cell[indexPath.row])
}
```

I want to use the result that is printed in a label on another ViewController.

How do I get the string value from the function and then use it on on the other view? My thought is to use a global variable but I need to get the string value out first.

Comment: Do you want to display another view controller from the `didSelectRowAt` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, You can use simple organization of a singleton of another ViewController (`SecondScreen`) with var **`main`** (in case, as usual, when `SecondScreen` inited via a Storyboard):

```
class SecondScreen : UIViewController {
    // 1. add this var
    static var main : SecondScreen? = nil

    // 2. Your some UI element
    @IBOutlet weak var textButton: UIButton!

    // 3. add this method
    func updateUI(string : String) {
        textButton.setTitle(string, for: .normal)
    }

    // 4. setting a var
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if SecondScreen.main == nil {
            SecondScreen.main = self
        }
    }

    // ... another your and standard methods
}
```

And you can update your SecondScreen like this:

```
    let v = SecondScreen.main
    v?.updateUI(string: "yourString")
```

Also I recommend you to call method async:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    SecondScreen.main?.updateUI(withString : string)
}
```

I suggest you to learn more about singletons...

Answer (score 0):

At first, when you create a `tableView`, you have to collect data (*string* here) of cells in an array or another data collection. And you can get a needed data (*strings*) with **`indexPath`** variable in the method **`didSelectRowAt`**. And you can pass the string to another `ViewController` (let use **`SecondViewController`**) with several ways.

Here is an example:

```
// declaration an array of your strings
var array : [String] = ["First", "Second", "Third", ...]
...
// getting a string from method:
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
let string = array[indexPath.row]
print(string)
// next, for example, you need to pass the string to a singleton SecondViewController with static var **main**:
SecondViewController.main?.neededString = string
}
```

Don't forget update in async DispatchQueue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    SecondViewController.main?.updateUI(withString : string)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that is working however I have to go to another page and then back before the second view controller updates. How would I force the second view controller to update in real time

Comment: Try this ways:
      
1) You have to have an instance of second ViewController in some variable (Second VC can be a controller of subview or superview). And you can call a method of second VC, where you can change it's UI. 
      2) If you haven't an instance, you can init second VC with your string.

Comment: the second view is actually an external monitor, the idea is that when a cell is clicked it displays the value of the cell in a label on the external monitor. I am very new to swift but i basically just need to refresh the external view. is that right?

Comment: You can learn and use a variety of techniques:
1. a singleton,
2. the Notification Center and wait for updates,
3. use a delegates and protocols' methods,
4. use a blocks, 
5. use a timer and listening the UserDefaults (crazy, but works).

Some ways are described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)

Comment: I get an error saying SecondScreen has no member 'main'

Comment: Yes, you need to organize a singleton class.